# datagridview data to list, then binding listbox to list, doesnt work?

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I cant realize what is wrong here so that listBox is empty, instead of having one list inside?(Probably very easy to solve but I cant get it on my own yet)

```
public List<Karta> ubaciUListu()
{
      List<Karta> Lista1 = new List<Karta>();
      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
      {

          Karta k = new Karta(0,"","");
          // k.Id =(int)row.Cells[0].Value;
          k.Pojam =(string) row.Cells[1].Value;
          k.Opis = (string)row.Cells[2].Value;

          Lista1.Add(k);


      }
      return Lista1;
  }

  private void btnNovaF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //ubaciUListu();
      this.Hide();
      Form2 f2 = new Form2();
      f2.ShowDialog();

  }
```

First I am creating List from data in dgv(see here [data in dgv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa36d.png))
then I am trying to bind listBox to this List

```
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        List<Karta> nova = f1.ubaciUListu();
        if(nova.Count!=0)
        { 
        lstBox.DataSource = nova;
        }
    }
```

hope this will be helpful enough to detect issue. Thank you !

Comment: as Sajeetharan pointed out, the underline issue is that you are constructing a new `Form1` in your `Form2` constructor.. one in which `Form1.DataViewList1` (control) is empty.

Comment: I meant... one in which `f1.DataGridView1` (control) is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new instance of the form1, existing list will be cleared,

```
 Form1 f1 = new Form1();
 List<Karta> nova = f1.ubaciUListu();
```

Better way is to pass it to the 2nd form when you open it,

```
 Form2 f2 = new Form2(Lista1);
```

Your form2 should be,

```
List<Karta> nova = new List<Karta>();
public Form2(List<Karta> input)
   {  
     nova = input;
   }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. this is partially correct.. probably better to just assign to f2.DataSource in the button click scope though.

Comment: As Sajeetharan said 'when creating new instance of form1 existing list will be cleared'. Answer is great and helpful, just for sake of learning, I was thinking, than I would put between new instance of Form1 and List<Karta> nova = f1.ubaciUListu();, this line:f1.ubaciUListu();. I see its not working, but I thought than list would be full again ?why not now ?

Comment: @mike_cus, you should avoid creating new instances of `Form1` altogether in the constructor of `Form2`.. the first code snippet here depicts where the issue is, the last one depicts how `Form2` constructor takes an existing instance of `List<Karta>` as a parameter which it assigns to a field that's defined on `Form2`; for your purposes: you'll also want to assign to `DataSource` as well. so add line `DataSource = nova;` after `nova = input;`

Comment: I got it. I wrote for sake of learning, apart from his answer which I already implemented in my small project, I was wondering why f1.ubaciUListu()(because problem is:When you create a new instance of the form1, existing list will be cleared,) wouldnt solve problem too(if that line is between two lines in first snippet), because I checked and it wouldnt. but, thanks for your effort ! :)